# How use packages that i downloaded with composer?

Tags: php, package, load

I'm downloaded three packages by composer, but i don't know how import them to my code. I want import all the three packages instead import file by file.

But I get the error 'Unable to load the requested class: apimati'

So I tried other way

```
     $this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'thrid_party');
     $this->load->view('apimatic');
     $this->load->view('mashape');
     $this->load->view('mundipagg');
```

But I get the error 'Unable to load the requested class: apimati.php'

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following line at the beginning of your script.

```
require 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Look at [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Comment: Thanks Michael, one more doubt, i have in production the same project, but doesnt has an vendor folder in production, will be there any error in this case? if I utilize require 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php'?

Comment: Of course errors will be!
When you run **composer install** or **composer require** it download packages from packagist.org to vendor folder(by default) and at the end it creates autoload file with "class mapping" for downloaded packages.
So, nothing will work without vendor folder.